# C# - short check for null

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How do I replace the following code

```
if (customer.Person!=null)
 Console.WriteLine(customer.Person.Name);
```

with something like this

```
Console.WriteLine(customer.Person.Name?? "unknown");
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't, I'm afraid - there's nothing like Groovy's null-safe dereferencing operator :(

I suppose you could create a "null object" for Person - i.e. a real instance, but with all the properties null. Then you could use:

```
Console.WriteLine((customer.Person ?? Person.Null).Name ?? "Unknown");
```

... but that's pretty horrible. (It's also not checking for `customer` being null.)

Another option would be to write an extension method on Person:

```
public static string NameOrDefault(this Person person, string defaultName)
{
    return person == null ? defaultName : person.Name ?? defaultName;
}
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine(customer.Person.NameOrDefault("Unknown");
```

Comment: What does "Person.Null" mean?

Comment: @Alex: That would be a static property in the Person class, returning the special "null object" Person reference, which has all its properties null.

Comment: @Alex: It is a static property returning an instance of Person representing "no person". This is the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: @Jon, 'Person.Empty' would be clearer, and similar to Microsoft naming conventions (string, EventArgs, Color, Guid, Uri...). Besides that, it's the best answer.

Comment: @HuBeZa: Hmm... I think I'd expect Person.Empty to return empty strings for all the properties instead. Possible Person.AllPropertiesNull? That's pretty explicit :)

Comment: You are right @Jon, I read null but my mind auto-interpret it as empty. What about `Person.AllReferenceTypePropertiesNullAndAllValueTypePropertiesDefault`?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(customer.Person != null ? customer.Person.Name : "unknown");
```

Not the best-looking code, but still a one-liner.

---

Edit: don't forget to use [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx), in case your application logic treats empty & null strings the same.